# Error when running pip install -r requirements.txt

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pywin32, read-the-docs

to build and run a local instance, im following the tutorial at
https://haha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
but i use the git repo
https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org.git
instead of
https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org.git
for the "git clone" command, as the link in the tutorial does not exist.
i am also using `venv`, and not `virtualenv`, as i was not able to make `virtualenv` work.

i then get to the step to run the following command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and everything seems to install fine, and then i get a list of

```
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <package>
```

followed by

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==227; sys_platform == "win32" (from docker) (from versions: 302, 303)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==227; sys_platform == "win32"
```

this is the last bit of the output

```
Collecting cssselect>0.7.9
  Using cached cssselect-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting lxml>=2.1
  Using cached lxml-4.8.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (3.6 MB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-crispy-forms to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-formtools to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of markdown to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of regex to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of stripe to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-kombu to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pytz to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-gravatar2 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of orjson to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of python-dateutil to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pyquery to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of selectolax to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-elasticsearch-dsl to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of elasticsearch-dsl to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of elasticsearch to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of gitpython to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of requests-oauthlib to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-allauth to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of celery to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of redis to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pygments to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pyyaml to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of slumber to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of requests-toolbelt to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of requests to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of jsonfield to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-vanilla-views to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of drf-extensions to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of drf-flex-fields to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-filter to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of sphinx to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of djangorestframework to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-simple-history to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-autoslug to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-polymorphic to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-extensions to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of virtualenv to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pip to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting pip==22.0.4
  Using cached pip-22.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==227; sys_platform == "win32" (from docker) (from versions: 302, 303)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==227; sys_platform == "win32"
```

Comment: Please include your python version and OS in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using python 3.10 which does not have a whl file available on PyPi for `pywin32==227`. Try the installation with a lower python version e.g. 3.9

Comment: this worked,
it seemed to not work in 3.8 and 3.7, perhaps because of syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to downgrade pip to something less than 20.2, and, it's likely that it will install what you want much faster and may resolve the issue